# GUI keeps crashing because of image loading?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, awt

I am currently trying to create a game for a class and I've decided to try and load the GUI and and display a background image.

However, I decided to create a singleton ImageLoader class that has a HashMap that caches images already loaded once and stores and/or returns new BufferedImages. The main purpose of this is to easily and efficiently access sprites for the multiple enemy entities/missiles fired that will be implemented soon.

Now the Game class is not complete, but it should run, which it does! Just not as I expected.

I would expect it to run and display a GUI with a background image, but the GUI shows up for a split second and then crashes.

**Here is the Game class (the drawing of the image in in the runGameLoop method)**

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas{

private JFrame frame;
private BufferStrategy strat;
private boolean stillPlaying;


public Game(){
    frame = new JFrame("Pirate Game!");

    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    frame.getContentPane().add(this);
    setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    setBounds(0,0,800,600);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    this.createBufferStrategy(2);
    strat = getBufferStrategy();
    stillPlaying = true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game g = new Game();
    g.runGameLoop();
}

private void runGameLoop() {
    long initLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //while(stillPlaying){
        long change = initLoop - System.currentTimeMillis();
        initLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Graphics2D gfx = (Graphics2D) strat.getDrawGraphics();
        BufferedImage sourceImage = ImageLoader.getImageLoader().getImage("resources/Untitled.jpg");
        gfx.drawImage(sourceImage,0,0,null);
    //}
}

}
```

**And here is the ImageLoader class**

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class ImageLoader {

private HashMap<String,BufferedImage> storedImages = new HashMap<String,BufferedImage>();
private static ImageLoader single = new ImageLoader();

public static ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return single;
}

public BufferedImage getImage(String place) {
    BufferedImage image=null;
    if (storedImages.containsKey(place))
        return storedImages.get(place);
    else{
        try{
            URL location =  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(place);
            if(location == null)
                System.exit(0);

            image = ImageIO.read(location);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        storedImages.put(place,image);
        return storedImages.get(place);
    }
}


}
```

Thank you for any help! I'm open to criticism.

Comment: I suspect your images aren't where you think they are...

Comment: What's the crash? Exception? What's the exception, stack trace and line in these files where the stack trace refers to...

Comment: In your catch, take out the `System.exit` and replace the SOP with `ex.printStackTrace().` See what you get

Comment: I did as peeskillet said and also removed both System.exits. it ends up giving me the following errors:                                       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
 at com.apcsz.anish_danny.ImageLoader.getImage(ImageLoader.java:29)
 at com.apcsz.anish_danny.Game.runGameLoop(Game.java:51)
 at com.apcsz.anish_danny.Game.main(Game.java:42)                                               So I'm assuming my images aren't in the right place but for some reason even if I move them to the same directory I get the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You images should be in the same package as the class trying to load them. An easy fix is to just copy all the images (if you're using an IDE), right - click on the package, and paste. As long as you just using the image file name as the path i.e. "mypic.png", it should work fine.

---

**EDIT**

So I got it to work to stop shutting down. All I did was change this

```
URL location =  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(place);
```

To

```
URL location =  this.getClass().getResource(place);
```

Only problem, is the image wasn't painting. I'm not exactly sure how `Canvas` works, it AWT, I'm only really familiar with Swing, so I changed it to a `JPanel` and overrode the `paintComponent` method. And made a few other subtle changes. You can check it out. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel {

    private JFrame frame;
    private BufferStrategy strat;
    private boolean stillPlaying;

    public Game() {
        frame = new JFrame("Pirate Game!");

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(this);
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        stillPlaying = true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game g = new Game();
        g.runGameLoop();
    }

    private void runGameLoop() {
        long initLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // while(stillPlaying){
        long change = initLoop - System.currentTimeMillis();
        initLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Graphics2D gfx = (Graphics2D) strat.getDrawGraphics();
        //BufferedImage sourceImage = ImageLoader.getImageLoader().getImage(
                //"stackoverflow.png");
        //gfx.drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, null);
        // }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        BufferedImage sourceImage = ImageLoader.getImageLoader().getImage(
                "stackoverflow.png");
        g.drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }

}
```

---

Another way that would've worked is if your `resources` was in the `src` folder. Maybe it wasn't before

[image]

Then the code snippets you used before would've worked

```
BufferedImage sourceImage = ImageLoader.getImageLoader().getImage(
                "resources/stackoverflow.png");
```

.....

```
URL location = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(place);
```

Note, in the above scenario, when using `getClass().getResource()`, without the `classLoader()`, your path should start with a `/`

Comment: Unfortunately still causing issues with the same errors. I'm getting an illegal argument exception: input == null although I don't know where null as an argument is coming from

Comment: remove the `resources/` from your path.

Comment: I had already done so, thank you for all your help so far though (still not working)

Comment: Which IDE are you using, and what's the complete package name you're using. Let me test it out.

Comment: Eclipse and the package name is com.apcsz.anish_danny

Comment: @Rycerub: See also the examples cited in the [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for [tag:embedded-resource].

Comment: See my **EDIT** I was able to fix the problem for you.